# didselectrowatindexpath not called

Tags: ios

I am facing a problem where the didselectrowatindexpath is not getting called.
My tableview is set in viewdidload as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //[super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.detailViewController = (klViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];

}
```

Now my cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called and I am reusing the cells as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"menuSelection1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    AmbassadorInfoData * data = [self.LoadMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = data.treeName;

    return cell;
}
```

I have checked other answers and mostly said that there could be the use of didDeselectRowAtIndexPath might be used. But this is not the case here.
Now my problem is in my split view controller whenever I select any option the corresponding detail view doesn't get displayed and is blank. None of my methods in the rootview  controller (klViewController) gets called. What could be the reason for this?
Following are the all methods related to UITableView. It is implemented in the same class as in viewDidLoad

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.LoadMenuItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"menuSelection1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    AmbassadorInfoData * data = [self.LoadMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = data.treeName;

    return cell;
}

-(NSArray *)LoadMenuItems
{


    NSMutableArray * menuData =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    AmbassadorInfoData * data = [[AmbassadorInfoData alloc] init];

    data.treeName = @"Ambassador Info";
    data.treeDescription = @"This is temp data.";
    NSString * file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"oak" ofType:@"jpg"];
    data.treePhoto = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];

    [menuData addObject:data];
    data=nil;

    data = [[AmbassadorInfoData alloc] init];
    data.treeName = @"AmbassadorInternalList";
    data.treeDescription = @"This is temp data.).";
    file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DouglasFir" ofType:@"jpg"];
    data.treePhoto = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];
    [menuData addObject:data];
    data=nil;

    data = [[AmbassadorInfoData alloc] init];
    data.treeName = @"Text 3";
    data.treeDescription = @"This is temp data.";
    file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SugarMaple" ofType:@"jpg"];
    data.treePhoto = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];
    [menuData addObject:data];
    data=nil;

    data = [[AmbassadorInfoData alloc] init];
    data.treeName = @"Text 4";
    data.treeDescription = @"This is temp data.";
    file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RedMaple" ofType:@"jpg"];
    data.treePhoto = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];
    [menuData addObject:data];
    data=nil;

    data = [[AmbassadorInfoData alloc] init];
    data.treeName = @"Text 5";
    data.treeDescription = @"This is temp data.";
    file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Pine" ofType:@"jpg"];
    data.treePhoto = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];
    [menuData addObject:data];
    menuItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)menuData];
    data=nil;

    return menuItems;


}




#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    AmbassadorInfoData * selectedItem =(AmbassadorInfoData *)[self.menuItems objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];


    detailObject = selectedItem;

    [detailViewController setDetailItem:detailObject];


}

@end
```

Comment: I think you have not set the delegate

Comment: show your all methods related to UITableView.  @Vinu1991, see his viewDidLoad method.

Comment: why is your [super viewDidLoad] commented out? are you storing all your UITableViewDelegate methods in the same class (not KLViewController?)

Comment: is it didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called, or nothing happens when it's called? Two different directions for a possible reason. If you put NSLog(@"it works! problem is in detailViewController assignment") on the first line of didSelectRow, please confirm that you see nothing in the logs...

Comment: Hi Andrei, Nothing gets printed in the logs...

Comment: Is anything working? Does the table view show the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try these modifications:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"TableView methods are called! problem is getting AmbassadorInfoData object") 

    AmbassadorInfoData * selectedItem =(AmbassadorInfoData *)[self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!selectedItem) NSLog(@"Unable to get Ambassador object, check your menuItems");

    [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:selectedItem];   //notice "self."


}
```

also, uncomment [super viewDidLoad];

EDIT:

it appears that you are using the code you don't understand, in this case i am suggesting to learn some basics....here's a [great site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) that helped me understand things quite a few times

and this is a guide from Apple: [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: Andrei thanks for ur replies. Can you pls. explain what is meant when you say that assigning view controller to a variable? In my detail view controller (KLViewController) I have certain actions like printing the description and the image. I am using placeholders for the image and text in the storyboard. Problem is didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not getting hit. MY leftside view controller displays the name properly as in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: first make sure that the method gets called by running the code above with all the NSLog lines, and reply here with what you see in the logs

Comment: The logs are empty and I also checked whether the method gets called. The method is not getting called.

Comment: if you see nothing in the logs, and your cellforrow is called and tableview is populated - you have to review your uitableview setup. There could be too many reasons and it's hard to narrow it down with the code you provided. Look in: IB tableview settings(rows selectable etc), set delegates from IB (as opposed to in ViewDidLoad)

Comment: I have copy pasted the code from the net. Could that be a reason for my problem in the setup. Will iOS not give me the template when I am subclass from <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>. If that is the case how do i autogenerate the methods?

Comment: my suggestion is to follow some tutorial that will give you understanding of what the lines mean. Without understanding of what each line does, you won't go far without meeting an error you can't solve. i'm going to update my answer with some links.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your program is stuck in a long running operation because of the way you're using LoadMenuItems. Every time numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, you're recreating the entire array -- this is bad. You should call LoadMenuItems once, in viewDidLoad perhaps, and once you've created that array, use it, not a call to LoadMenuItems when you need to get data out. I don't know if this is what is causing your problem, but you should definitely fix it, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I tried creating the array in viewDidLoad and returning the menuItems from the LoadMenuItems. Now the creation of the array is happening only once when I debug. Even then the detail view in the split view is not getting displayed...

Comment: @user2021014, is didSelectRowAtIndexPath still not being called?

Comment: Hi Rdelmar, I have uploaded the snippets of the code at this link https://gist.github.com/anandfrancis/4993216

Comment: @user2021014, Unfortunately, the code isn't real useful without knowing what's happening in the storyboard also. If you want me to take a look at the project, you can email it to me at rdelmar@comcast.net, otherwise there's not much I can do.